# Operator [backend] create unique cart link for customer - extension? code? method?

Tags: product, cart, customer, cart-items

several times per day customers e-mail us: "hi, the coupon code is not working", or "I can't add 3 products to my cart" .... and more problems like that. Very often we send a step by step procedure how they can do whatever they want succesfully.

But that made me think: would it be possible for our operators to create a link from the backend, or frontend for that matter, that we can send to the customer. If the customer clicks the link:
- a cart (that we made for them) is already activated
- and a coupon code is also already activated

In other words: can we create a cart for the customer from the backend? A cart that we then can then hand over to the customer by sending a link?

(I hope this is clear and appreciate your help)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cart on the frontend and then generate a link to share it with your customer.

Need a development to

- Generate the sharing link (for a specific user, an IP, ....)
- A controller to restore the shared cart

It can work like an abandoned cart.

Or for registered users

- A common password to log on customer account

My 2 cents,

Comment: something like this: http://shop.sutunam.com/share-cart-magento-extension.html (but has no IP filter - yet)

Comment: yep, don't know sutunam but the extension seems to do the job (adding an Ip filter or a restriction to a specific customer should be easy to do)